# Console Window showing in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, console

So for some reason the console shows alongside my windows form. How can I close the console window?

Answer (score 4):

Try switching the Output Type to "Windows Application" instead of "Console Application" (Right-click on Project --> Properties --> Right hand side of the window shown).

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio. And why would someone downvote my question?

Comment: Because your question is VERY low quality, you don't explain, what the exact problem is.